# every machine has a particular file with a specified path. need to write bash command to capture that information

Tags: bash, scripting

```
cd /home/bin/x1/machine_name_service_details
```

for example:

```
1. cd /home/bin/x1/machine1_service_details

2. cd /home/bin/x1/machine2_service_details
```

I want to capture the following information which is present inside this file.  How does string formatting works in Linux machine?

I have tried the following code, but it did not work:

```
HOST=`hostname`

printf"/home/bin/x1/"%s"_service_details" "$HOST"
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "didn't work"? What did you expect it to do? What did it do instead?

Comment: You need a space after `printf`. Voting to close as trivial typo.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
printf "/home/bin/x1/"$HOST"_service_details"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `printf` let it process the args

```
printf '/home/bin/x1/%s_service_details\n' "$HOST"
```